# Fourier transform of an equation

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have the following equation:

$$m \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = -Kx - \alpha \frac{dx}{dt} + f(t) $$

Which I introduced into Mathematica as:

```
eqn = m D[x[t], {t, 2}] == -K x + f[t] - a D[x[t], t]
```

I want to take the Fourier transform of this equation  to get (after simplyfing terms):

$$ x(\omega) [ - m \omega^2 + i \omega \alpha + K] = f(\omega)$$

(There might be a prefactor missing because I defined the Fourier transform as the inverse Fourier transform of the one that Mathematica uses but that is not important).

In order to do that I tried:

```
FourierTransform[f[t], t, \[Omega]]
```

But the output that I get is just:

```
FourierTransform[ m x''[t] == -K x + f[t] -   a x'[t], t, \[Omega]]
```

It seems that Mathematica doesn't know how to do the Fourier transform of the functions $x(t)$ and $f(t)$ without their explicit form. Is there any way to do this directly with the built in functions of Mathematica?